# How to make correlation matrix with especific columns in R

Tags: r

I have a multi-column dataframe that can be divided into two categories: land use and water quality.

I would like to analyze the correlation only between water quality variables and land use variables, without there being a correlation between land use variables and a correlation between quality variables.

I am using package corrplot() spearmen method but i dont know how i can ignore correlation between categories.

Landuse = veg, wet, dry, water

Quality water = OD, DBO, DQO

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(corrplot)


veg<-c(1,2,3,2.3,4.1)
wet<-c(2,2.3,1.9,2.5,2.2)
dry<-c(5,5.1,6.9,4.3,5.3)
water<-c(0.69,0.75,0.81,0.82,0.82)
coli<-c(10,11,12,13,9.7)
OD<-c(1,3,2.5,2.7,1.8)
DBO<-c(7,8,9,6.5,8)
DQO<-c(3.5,4,4.1,3,2)

#landuse=veg, wet, dry, water
#quality water = OD, DBO, DQO

data_land<-data.frame(veg, wet, dry, water, OD, DBO, DQO)

correl<-corrplot(cor(as.matrix(data_land),method = "spearman"),
                 method = "color",
                  tl.cex = 0.9,
                 number.cex = 0.95,
                 addCoef.col = "black")
```

[image]

For example, I don't want the correlation between DQO and DBO to be calculated, as they are quality parameters. I also don't want the correlation between veg and dry to be calculated, as they are land use classes, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate your Spearman correlations between land and water variables by selecting columns when calling `cor`. The function `cor` can alternatively accept a second matrix to compute correlations - so you can compute correlations between a "land use" matrix (columns 1-4) and a "water quality" matrix (columns 5-7):

```
my_cor <- cor(data_land[, 1:4], 
              data_land[, 5:7], 
              method = "spearman")

corrplot(my_cor,
         method = "color",
         tl.cex = 0.9,
         number.cex = 0.95,
         addCoef.col = "black")
```

**Plot**

[image: correlation plot]

---

If you instead want a square correlation plot, with empty spaces where you did not want to show correlations, you could try calculating correlations as you had before, set correlation results to `NA` for those you want to hide, and then set `na.label` to an empty space in `corrplot`:

```
my_cor <- cor(data_land, method = "spearman")

my_cor[1:4, 1:4] <- NA
my_cor[5:7, 5:7] <- NA

corrplot(my_cor,
         na.label = " ",
         method = "color",
         tl.cex = 0.9,
         number.cex = 0.95,
         addCoef.col = "black")
```